# How do I create a relation between the view part and the model part in MVC design in Java?

Tags: java, swing, exception

The app is a small Chess game. In my modelling classes I have a board class which has an [8][8] array of squares.

Now what I did to paint the squares (I'm not used to creating GUIs so it might be totally wrong) was that I looped through the array with two for loops as below:

(this is the class that draws the board)

```
 class Drawboard extends JComponent{
 Board board;
 public Drawboard(){
  repaint();
 }
 public void paint(Graphics g){ 
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
    int heigth = 20, width = 20;
    g.setColor(board.getSquare(i, j).getColour());
    g.drawRect(i*width, j*heigth, width, heigth);
    g.fillRect(i*width, j*heigth, width, heigth);
   }
  }
 } 
}
```

The 'board' variable is a reference variable to the Board instance in my Game class (if that's the way you reference to other classes)

(...and this is the method that adds the drawn board to a JPanel in my main view class)

```
 public void drawBoard(){
  gamePanel.add(new Drawboard());
 }
```

Is this bad coding?

I added my main view class as an object in my Game class, the main view class is the one that has the drawBoard() method. But when I try to run the app it gives me this in the console (and a solid grey window):

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Drawboard.paint(Graphic.java:50)
```

Not sure why I get that, as I said. I'm not used to writing GUIs and pretty new to programming overall.

This is the whole main view class this far:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Graphic extends JFrame {

 JFrame    gameWindow    = new JFrame("Chess");
 JPanel    gamePanel     = new JPanel();
 JMenuBar  gameMenu      = new JMenuBar();
 JButton   newGame  = new JButton("New game");
 JButton   pauseGame  = new JButton("Pause");
 JButton   actionLog  = new JButton("Action log");
 Timer    timer   = new Timer();

 Graphic(){
  gameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  gameWindow.setSize(180, 200);
  gameWindow.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
  gameWindow.setVisible(true);
  gamePanel.setVisible(true);
  gameMenu.add(newGame);
  gameMenu.add(pauseGame);
  gameMenu.add(actionLog);
  drawBoard();
 }

 public void drawBoard(){
  gamePanel.add(new Drawboard());
 }


}
```

Also, if this is the correct way to do the drawing. How do I connect one of the squares that are drawn to the squares in my Square[][] array?
Obviously if one square is clicked, I would want something to happen with the corresponding square in my model class.

If I'm right, as it is now, I won't be able to click single squares but just the whole board right? Seeing as it's one component.

Would it work to create a component that represents just a square, then create an array of that component? like drawSquare [][] or something.

The main "game" class that holds the board:

```
 public class Game {

 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 public static void main(String[] args) 
   throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
  Board board = new Board();
  Graphic view = new Graphic();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read the whole question but the problem seems here

```
class Drawboard extends JComponent{
 Board board;//un initilized
 .
 ..
 .
 public void paint(Graphics g){ 
   .
   .
    g.setColor(board.getSquare(i, j).getColour());//trying to invoke method on null

   }
  }
 } 
}
```

make it like

```
class Drawboard extends JComponent{
     Board board;//un initilized
     public Drawboard() {
         board = new Board();
     }
     .
     ..
     .
     public void paint(Graphics g){ 
       .
       .
        g.setColor(board.getSquare(i, j).getColour());//trying to invoke method on null

       }
      }
     } 
    }
```

Comment: I'm really not sure when it comes to refering to classes "outside of the class". The board is already initialized in my Game (model) class, isn't this going to create a totally different board?
Meaning, that if one piece moves in the board in my Game class, the same piece won't have executed the move in the Board instance in the Drawboard class?

Comment: I can't see initialization of Board